# Maximo inbox/assignments linking

Tags: maximo

I'm working on an existing workflow for work orders and there are two different applications that are receiving the information somehow: ICOM SR Work Order Tracking and ICOM Work Orders.

Since I'm not the one who developed these applications I'm not sure what is the reason/difference between the two.

My issue is that when an assignment arrives at a user's inbox and they click the description it takes them to the ICOM SR Work Order Tracking while I want it to take them to the ICOM Work Orders application instead. Where do I specify where the assignments link to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the workflow process which creates those assignments in Workflow Designer application, create new process revision, open Properties of the desired Task Node and pick the ICOM Work Orders application from "Application" lookup instead of ICOM SR Work Order Tracking (which should be there now) at the place I marked on screenshot (not the one in the header). Then deactivate older revision and activate your new revision of the process.

[image: screenshot]

That should do the job, hope this helps :-)